# Facebook Graph to show Event Attendees

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am looking to display the attendees for a given facebook event on a PHP page. Ideally it would be that graphical display with people's pictures displaying.

I believe this could be done using the facebook graph API, but the following is giving me an error requiring signature:

```
https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT uid FROM event_member WHERE eid =  ... AND rsvp_status = 'attending'
```

Also, how would I even get the eid? Can it simply be parsed off the end of an event page link?
    www.facebook.com/events/...eid#...

Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get event attendees you can run following [FQL](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/) query:

```
SELECT uid FROM event_member WHERE eid = "EXISTING_EVENT_ID"
```

Event id is something you can get from many sources, if you create event via [Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) you'll get event id as response. Or you can get ids of events current/specific user attending. Or as you already noted from URL of event page.

Next FQL query will return all events current user is attending:

```
SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid = me() AND rsvp_status = "attending"
```

Queries can be nested so you can do stuff like get list of all attendees of all events current user ever attended:

```
SELECT eid, uid FROM event_member WHERE eid IN (
  SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid = me() AND rsvp_status = "attending"
)
```

To get details of attendees for specific event something like this may do the work:

```
SELECT uid, name, pic_square FROM user WHERE uid IN (
  SELECT uid FROM event_member WHERE eid = "EXISTING_EVENT_ID"
)
```

**NOTES:**

- You'll need any valid `access_token` to get public events details.
- To retrieve events of current user you'll need `user_events` permission to be granted to your application by this user.
- You can display user image with only knowing his id with URL in format of `http://graph.facebook.com/{USER_ID}/picture`
- You can run FQL queries with Graph API by issuing `GET` request to `https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q={QUERY_HERE}`

For more details on [FQL](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/) and [Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) read documentation, especially on tables [`event_member`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/event_member/) and [`user`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/)

Comment: Thanks Juicy, I'm looking into the php sdk. My main problem is that I cannot locate how to display up to 6 user pictures with a total attendees next to it. Something such as "34 people attending" and the random images of 6 of those attendees.