# FQL Get All Attendees of All Events for a particular user

Tags: facebook-fql

So I've done a bit of reading up on the FQL documentation, but I haven't managed to find the answer to my current problem. Given a single user, I want to get back a list of attendees (per event) that are going to events that the user is also attending.

NOTE: (I am using a StringTemplate, so I provide the proper uid through the render function later)

With this query, I am able to get all the events for a particular user.

```
SELECT eid from event_member WHERE uid={{}} AND start_time > 0
```

With this query, I am able to get all the users for a single event.

```
SELECT uid, eid FROM event_member WHERE uid = {{}}

SELECT uid, eid FROM event_member WHERE eid in (SELECT eid FROM #a)
```

However, when I try the following query, which I found here: [Facebook Graph to show Event Attendees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8724581/facebook-graph-to-show-event-attendees)

```
SELECT eid, uid FROM event_member WHERE eid IN (SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid = {{}} AND rsvp_status = {{}})
```

I am returned with nothing. Any ideas? Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: Thanks Gergo for the formatting. Much appreciated!

Comment: `AND rsvp_status = {{}}`, why `{{}}`?

Comment: It's a StringTemplate. It takes a parameter in. In this case, I was using "attending" as the parameter. The same applies to uid

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so after some more research, I've decided to use the Facebook Graph API instead. This is what people are moving towards, eventually, so it's best to get on board.

The query I used in the graph api to get all attendees for all events that a particular user is also attending was:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v1.0/{{}}?fields=events.since(0).fields(name, attending)
```

This query will return the events the user is going to in addition to all of the other attendees per event.